# check if a command returns error before running script

Tags: linux, sh

I'm writing a small restore script and before I run the actual script I want to check if all commands work..

I want to check if `alias` is added correctly on `mysql`..

So if the command `# mysql` returns an error I want to write an error message and then exit the script

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql -e 'exit' >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "mysql failed"; exit 1; }
# mysql works fine
# Your commands here
```

You could execute mysql and exit if it fails (either command is not found or alias not set correctly). In case, `mysql` works as expected, just `exit` out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the return status of a command with the `$?' variable, but there is a simpler way:

```
if !mysql; then
   echo "An error has occured"
fi
```